# Proof of Period of Convolution

Tags: convolution, periodic-functions

I am having trouble with the following proof.
Let $y(t) = x(t) \ast h(t)$  (where $\ast$ denotes convolution of two functions).

Prove that if $x(t)$ is periodic, then $y(t)$ is periodic.

So I started off assuming $x(t)$ has some fundamental period, called $T$. But then, the question gives me no information about $h(t)$ and whether it is periodic, so I'm kind of stuck on how to go further with this question. I'm also pretty new to convolution, so I'm not super rock solid on all the convolution properties.

Comment: I have this weakness: I prefer writing $y(t) = (x*h)(t).$ For example, if $t=3$ then $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ and $y(t)$ are particular numbers $x(3), h(3), y(3).$ Should one then say that the particular number $y(3)$ is the convolution of the two particular numbers $x(3)$ and $h(3)$? Obviously not.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x(t+T)=x(t)$ and:
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t-\tau)h(\tau) \, d\tau$$
Then:
$$y(t+T)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t+T-\tau)h(\tau) \, d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t-\tau)h(\tau) \, d\tau=y(t)$$

Answer (score 3):

From the definition of convolution, we have$$
y(t)=(x∗h)(t)=\int_{-∞}^∞ x(τ)h(t−τ)\,\mathrm{d}τ.
$$
Suppose that $x(t)$ is periodic with period $T$, then we have $x (t)=x(t+T)$ and we can rewrite the above integral as$$
y(t)=\int_{-∞}^∞ x(τ+T)h(t−τ)\,\mathrm{d}τ.
$$
Now, we employ a change of variable. Let $λ=τ+T$ so that $τ=λ−T$ and $\mathrm{d}λ=\mathrm{d}τ$. This yields\begin{align*}
y(t)&=\int_{-∞}^∞ x(λ)h(t−(λ−T)) \,\mathrm{d}λ\\
&=\int_{-∞}^∞ x(λ)h(t+T−λ) \,\mathrm{d}λ\\
&=\int_{-∞}^∞ x(λ)h((t+T)−λ) \,\mathrm{d}λ\\
&=(x∗h)\bigr|_{v=t+T}=y(v)\bigr|_{v=t+T}=y(t+T).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $y(t)$ is periodic with period $T$.